# Can a tectonic plate subduct under one plate while another plate subducts under it along the same boundary?

Tags: geophysics, plate-tectonics, planetary-science

At a triple junction plate boundary there are three tectonic plates meeting. We have plenty of examples of these boundaries on Earth, notably the [Afar Triple Junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afar_Triple_Junction), [Mendocino Triple Junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendocino_Triple_Junction), and the extinct [South Greenland Triple Junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Greenland_Triple_Junction). The majority of these junctions are divergent. But what if two of the three boundaries were convergent?

I am currently working on a fantasy world but thought this question was more appropriate for this SE. This is the triple junction I am asking about.

[image]

The arrows that go under the colored lines are where the subducting is. The salmon line is convergent and the mint line is divergent.

I was wondering if it was possible for a plate to both subduct another plate and also be subducted on basically the same boundary.

Comment: I find your drawing a bit confusing as the right plate is moving two different directions?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest That was confusing, sorry. I also realized I had the wrong plates subducting.

Answer (score 1):

### On a large scale yes.

On a small scale you mostly get a complex mess of micro-plates created by the diverse forces.

[image]

[image]

A triple junction of any type of plate interaction can form, Japan has an all subduction triple junction.

Comment: Ok, cool. This is on a large scale. The plates are all much larger than the South American plate.